# How to load the new website IP in Windows?

Tags: windows, dns, ip, ipconfig

I'm trying to access a website but I can not make my computer or router to recognize the new IP address. Previously, it took little time for this to happen but lately I'm waiting up to 24 hours. How to force my computer or router to recognize the new website IP?

**Website:** http://facilityprint.com.br

**My PC load**: 186.202.153.98

**New IP address**: 104.207.244.82

[image]

Comment: @NetworkKingPin that is a bad idea. Adding the website to your hosts file will make it work on one computer, but it will not say anything about the DNS. any other person will still be having problems.

Comment: @LPChip Thank you for that. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 2):

The depends on the resolution of Domain Names on your system.
The easiest solution would be flushing the integrated cache for DNS entries in windows, by executing
    ipconfig /flushdns
After cosulting the OS's own cache, it  will ask the primary and secondary DNS server as configured in the IP settings - for a home user these settings are usually distributed by the local router via DHCP and the primary DNS is usually the router itself, which either caches or forwards the requests and provides information to the requesting computer.

In how far you are able to reset the router's own cache is depending on your router model.

Lastly if none of the caches is the cause of your "problem" the router gets wrong DNS entries from its own gateway.
This can be the case because bigger DNS services use caches that are only updated every once in a while, or because it is a poorly managed DNS server.

It can help setting the DNS server to Google's own DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.4.8.4), because they tend to be reliable. you can adjust that either on your local PC or on the router to take effect for all connected systems.

Another approach would be entering the DNS-IP into the systems "hosts" file (see %windir%\system32\drivers\etc), because this file is consulted by the system even before checking any cached DNS entries.

It would be wise though to remove a hosts-entry after a while, because this will be a static assignment forever until you change it.

Answer (score 1):

When altering DNS settings, you should always keep in mind that such changes take time to propagate over the internet. It can take from 2 to 48 hours before changes are replicated through all hops on the internet.

`ipconfig /flushdns` can be used to renew your DNS configuration with that from your router/modem/server (depending on what your DNS servers are) but if they were not updated yet, you will still get the old address.

I recommend setting your DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 which are google's DNS servers, and then issue an ipconfig /flushdns to renew your configuration. This should ensure that the domain is correctly configured. Eventually it will start working with your old configuration as well, but it might be required to reboot/restart the DNS provider in your network, such as router or service on your server.

Comment: OpenDNS or Google DNS don't work in my TCP/IPv4 Wifi adapter settings.

Comment: That's strange, it should. What error do you get?

Answer (score -2):

Use the commands

Ipconfig /release

This will release your current IP Address

ipconfig /renew

This will update your IP to whatever the newest one is.

Then try accessing the website.

Comment: renewing your ip address will not cause the DNS servers to be spoofed, so these commands are useless. ipconfig /flushdns is what you need to use in order to achieve that.